# Get data type of field in select statement in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, function, types

Can I get data types of each column I selected instead of the values, using a select statement?

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT a.name, a.surname, b.ordernum 
FROM customer a
JOIN orders b
ON a.id = b.id
```

and result should be like this

```
name    | NVARCHAR(100)
surname | NVARCHAR(100)
ordernum| INTEGER
```

or it can be in row like this, it isn't important:

```
name           |   surname     |  ordernum
NVARCHAR(100)  | NVARCHAR(100) |   INTEGER
```

Thanks

Comment: use 'desc table_name'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can query the `all_tab_columns` view in the database.

```
SELECT  table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length FROM all_tab_columns where table_name = 'CUSTOMER'
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not work for a query like this: `SELECT a.name, a.surname, TO_CHAR(b.ordernum) as ordernum_char`. For this you have to use package DBMS_SQL and use explicit cursors.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit An concrete example would be welcome.

Answer (score 52):

I found a not-very-intuitive way to do this by using `DUMP()`

```
SELECT DUMP(A.NAME), 
       DUMP(A.surname), 
       DUMP(B.ordernum) 
FROM   customer A 
       JOIN orders B 
         ON A.id = B.id
```

It will return something like:

`'Typ=1 Len=2: 0,48'` for each column.

`Type=1` means `VARCHAR2/NVARCHAR2`
`Type=2` means `NUMBER/FLOAT`
`Type=12` means `DATE`, etc.

You can refer to this oracle doc for information [Datatype Code](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58234/datatype.htm)
or this for a simple mapping [Oracle Type Code Mappings](https://ellebaek.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/oracle-type-code-mappings/)

Answer (score 12):

I usually create a view and use the `DESC` command:

```
CREATE VIEW tmp_view AS 
SELECT 
      a.name
    , a.surname
    , b.ordernum 
FROM customer a
  JOIN orders b
    ON a.id = b.id
```

Then, the `DESC` command will show the type of each field.

`DESC tmp_view`

Answer (score 4):

I came into the same situation. As a workaround, I just created a `view` (If you have privileges) and described it and dropped it later. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have privileges to create a view in Oracle, a "hack" around it to use MS Access :-(

In MS Access, create a pass through query with your sql (but add where clause to just select 1 record), create a select query from the view (very important), selecting all *, then create a make table from the select query. When this runs it will create a table with one record, all the data types should "match" oracle.
i.e. Passthrough --> Select --> MakeTable --> Table

I am sure there are other better ways, but if you have limited tools and privileges this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you have Toad for Oracle, you can highlight the statement and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> and you'll get a nice view of column and their datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Field data type data is available from client code in the [ODP.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core). Expect Oracle other libraries must support schema information too. It is straight forward in C# Script you just need a connection string and the SELECT statement. Ask for the Schema Data Only. This solution requires no extras CREATE VIEW rights needed with my testing so far. Resolves type on select expressions. Con is does add extra round trips to data base.

The example is using c# 10 ,may need to downgrade the syntax. The Constants.ContainerConnectionString is a connection string and the Constants.DvcrSyntax can be any select statement.

```cs
using System.Data;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using OracleSchemaSample;

var connectionBuilder =
    new OracleConnectionStringBuilder(Constants.ContainerConnectionString)
    {
        ConnectionTimeout = 30,
        Enlist = "false",
        PersistSecurityInfo = true
    };
await using var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionBuilder.ConnectionString);
await using var command = new OracleCommand(Constants.DvcrSyntax, connection);
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    await connection.OpenAsync(cts.Token);
    connection.ModuleName = "MyUnqueApplicatonName";
    connection.ClientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Tracing identity
    await using var schemaReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly, cts.Token);
    var columnSchema = await schemaReader.GetColumnSchemaAsync(cts.Token);
    foreach (var column in columnSchema)
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"{column.ColumnOrdinal}\t{column.ColumnName}\t{column.DataType}\t{column.DataTypeName}\t{column.ColumnSize}");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
you can use the DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2

    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    STMT CLOB;
    CUR NUMBER;
    COLCNT NUMBER;
    IDX NUMBER;
    COLDESC DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB2;
BEGIN
    CUR := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    STMT := 'SELECT  object_name , to_char(object_id), created FROM    DBA_OBJECTS where rownum<10';

    SYS.DBMS_SQL.PARSE(CUR, STMT, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2(CUR, COLCNT, COLDESC);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Statement: ' || STMT);
    FOR IDX IN 1 .. COLCNT
    LOOP
        CASE COLDESC(IDX).col_type
        WHEN 2 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('#' || TO_CHAR(IDX) || ': NUMBER');
        WHEN 12 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('#' || TO_CHAR(IDX) || ': DATE');
        WHEN 180 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('#' || TO_CHAR(IDX) || ': TIMESTAMP');
        WHEN 1 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('#' || TO_CHAR(IDX) || ': VARCHAR'||':'|| COLDESC(IDX).col_max_len);
        WHEN 9 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('#' || TO_CHAR(IDX) || ': VARCHAR2');
        -- Insert more cases if you need them
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('#' || TO_CHAR(IDX) || ': OTHERS (' || TO_CHAR(COLDESC(IDX).col_type) || ')');
        END CASE;
    END LOOP;
    SYS.DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(CUR);
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM(SQLCODE()) || ': ' || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
        SYS.DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(CUR);
END;
/


full example in the below url

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/sk/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055146.html
```

Comment: This looks like an answer for DB2, and the question is about Oracle.